error: The define key "process.env.CommonProgramFiles(x86)" contains invalid identifier "CommonProgramFiles(x86)"
Previously I got the error says  error TS1343: The 'import.meta' meta-property is only allowed when the '--module' option is 'es2020', 'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', 'node16', or 'nodenext'. while running test file in jest.
To solve above error I search on google and I found one solution from stack overflow,
after applied those changes my testcases passed successfully but when I build the project with command yarn build:dev throwing below error.
yarn build:dev
yarn run v1.22.19
$ vite build --mode development
The CJS build of Vite's Node API is deprecated. See https://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#vite-cjs-node-api-deprecated for more details.
vite v5.2.8 building for development...
✓ 4 modules transformed.
x Build failed in 135ms
error during build:
Error: [commonjs--resolver] Transform failed with 2 errors:
error: The define key "process.env.CommonProgramFiles(x86)" contains invalid identifier "CommonProgramFiles(x86)"
error: The define key "process.env.ProgramFiles(x86)" contains invalid identifier "ProgramFiles(x86)"
file: D:/DemoWebsite/node_modules/react/jsx-runtime.js

As per one solution I have add vite-plugin-environment and babel-plugin-transform-import-meta packages
and change import.meta.env to process.env in my project pages and components also made some changes on below files.
vite.config.js
export default defineConfig({
    define: {
        "process.env": {}
    },
    plugins: [... , **EnvironmentPlugin("all")**],
    esbuild: {
        jsxFactory: "h",
        jsxFragment: "Fragment"
        // ... other options
    },
    envDir: "./src/environments"
})

**babel.config.js **
module.exports = {
    plugins: ["babel-plugin-transform-import-meta"]
}


ts.config.json
"types": [
            "**node**",
            "vite/client",
            "@testing-library/jest-dom"
        ]

here is my page code
**pages/AboutUs/index.tsx
**
const AboutUs = ({ toast }: types.PageProps) => {
return (
    <>
        <h1>language:</h1>
        <h2>process.env.VITE_LANG</h2> //previously it was import.meta.env.VITE_LANG
    </>
     )

}
about.test.tsx
describe("About Page", () => {
const mockToast = jest.fn()
it("renders without crashing and check language dropdown", () => {
    const { getByText} = render(<AboutUs toast={mockToast} />)
    expect(getByText("language:")).toBeInTheDocument()
})

})

I too faced this issue in my Windows machine. I had to get those system environments removed in the Vite build process. You could do the following in your vite.config.js file
// Clear specific environment variables
delete process.env['CommonProgramFiles(x86)'];
delete process.env['ProgramFiles(x86)'];

export default defineConfig({...


// vite.config.ts

// List of problematic environment variables
const problematicEnvVars = [
  'CommonProgramFiles(x86)',
  'ProgramFiles(x86)',
  'IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition'
];

// Remove the problematic environment variables
problematicEnvVars.forEach((varName) => {
  delete process.env[varName];
});

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
  // Your existing Vite configuration
});


I too faced this issue in my Windows machine. You could do the following in your vite.config.js file
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), 'VITE_');
  return {
// your vite config
}
}


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

In your vite.config.ts


export default defineConfig({
  // your configs
  plugins: [
    EnvironmentPlugin('all', { prefix: 'VITE_' }), // add this prefix to solve the issue
    // other plugin configs
  ],
});




Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
